# ipv4.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast and ipv6.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast inside docker container

Tags: docker

Why are different values for `sysctl` parameter

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast=1
```

and

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast=0
```

inside docker container even though corresponding host has both of them as enabled?

```
set net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast=1, net.ipv6.conf.default.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast=1
```

and created docker container.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think this depends on the base image you're using, check this first